# Serving a different product page for certain products with router

Tags: magento-1.9, module, xml, controllers, routing

I've developed a module that sends some product pages to a product customization wizard. I've used `getProductUrl()` to change the links to point to the customization URL.

```
http://mywebsite.com/designer/?id=417&size=21
```

I now want to use the original URL, but serve up the content of the new URL.

```
http://mywebsite.com/custom-rectangle-name-tag-1-5-x-3-5
```

I want this only to happen for products that use my customization module. The logic for this already exists in `getProductUrl()`. My question is where can I put this logic?

I've tried to send the product route to my module. I've put the route for products in my config.xml as is. This doesn't reroute it, nor would I expect it to. (extraneous information left out).

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <catalog>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mage_Catalog</module>
                    <frontName>catalog</frontName>
                </args>
            </catalog>
        </routers>
        <default>
            <router>catalog</router>
        </default>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

I've put in the controller I've wished to use, but it serves a 404.

```
        <routers>
            <catalog>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>HSC_PCE</module>
                    <frontName>pce</frontName>
                </args>
            </catalog>
        </routers>
```

I've also tried putting it inside of my namespace like so. It gives the original product page.

```
        <routers>
            <hsc_pce>
                <catalog>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>HSC_PCE</module>
                        <frontName>designer</frontName>
                    </args>
                </catalog>
            </hsc_pce>
        </routers>
```

Even if this did work, if it wasn't a customization wizard product, how would I serve the original route?

How can I serve a different page to my customization wizard products?

Answer (score 0):

I found that to accomplish this, I didn't need to look at the router, but instead the product controller. In this case, I needed to catch the request at `catalog/controllers/ProductController.php` at the `viewAction()` function and extended that function in my module as appropriate.